# Android Support: Does Android support character entities such as divide and multiply

Tags: java, android, unicode

In a scientific calculator app I'm making, I have character entities such as divide and multiply. I was wondering if Android supports this natively. I'm currently using unicode to display the divide symbol (\u00F7), but can I just input ÷? Or will earlier versions of Android show the divide symbol up as boxes if I don't use unicode. Note that I'm displaying the text programmatically.

Comment: "but can I just input ÷?" -- input ÷ into *what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML entities.

`android:text="&#247;"` in a Button text will display a division symbol.

I believe you could also try the `÷` character

Comment: So Unicode isn't supported fully yet? I'm setting the text in Java, and when I input an HTML entity, it shows up as the HTML Entity itself.

Comment: Haven't tried unicode. How are you setting the value?

Comment: button.setText("\u00F7");

Comment: Why do it from Java?